# cocos2d hide/show sprites with animation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i am spending a lot for my time for a simple things i think.I want to hide and show a sprite
in scene.

```
 myS = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Background_Pause_pad.png"];
    [myS setPosition:ccp(384,470)];
     myS.opacity = 0;
    [self addChild:myS z:1];
```

and when i need to appear it..

```
[myS runAction:[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:1]];
```

and hide it

```
[myS runAction:[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1]];
```

but it does not work.....can anyone plz help??

Answer (score 5):

1. Why do you use a Sequence for one action ?
2. You have to choose the animation you want !
3. E.g : if you choose CCFadeIn

> ```
> [mySprite runAction:[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:0.5f]];
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try the below stuff of the code. It would work for you

```
id action1 = [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:1];
id action2 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1];
id action3 = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1];

[myS runAction:[CCSequence actions:action1,action2,action3,nil]];
```

As you need the fadein fadeout action it would generate it and display the Same.